# How api calls are done with headers in swift

Tags: ios, swift, rest, api

I want to securely provide my data from the API using JWT token.So Currently I have implemented security in the backend and each ajax call eith the header

```
url:"https://dataurl,
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        headers : TokenHeader(),
```

But now I want to send the same data to be consumed by an IOS App which is developed in swift.I am not a IOS mobile developer and when I look into how they make the rest calls I found that something like this can be done:

```
let todosEndpoint: String = "https://dataurl"
guard let todosURL = URL(string: todosEndpoint) else {
  print("Error: cannot create URL")
  return
}
var todosUrlRequest = URLRequest(url: todosURL)
todosUrlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
let newTodo: [String: Any] = ["title": "My First todo", "completed": false, "userId": 1]
let jsonTodo: Data
do {
  jsonTodo = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: newTodo, options: [])
  todosUrlRequest.httpBody = jsonTodo
} catch {
  print("Error: cannot create JSON from todo")
  return
}

let session = URLSession.shared

let task = session.dataTask(with: todosUrlRequest) {
  (data, response, error) in
  guard error == nil else {
    print("error calling POST on /todos/1")
    print(error)
    return
  }
  guard let responseData = data else {
    print("Error: did not receive data")
    return
  }
```

So now my question is like ajax call in my web app how to consume rest service from the mobile app side.Any help is appreciated?

Comment: I suggest that you use Alamofire and SwiftyJSON plugin. It is much easier using that plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use headers like this

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL)
request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like (depending on what header values you need to send):

```
todosUrlRequest.setValue("token value", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```